# Identifying 8051 garbage microcontrollers (updated)

Tags: microcontroller, troubleshooting

Here I am with another question about the 8051.

After researching various resources, I read in the datasheet that the ALE pin is enabled by default but can be disabled in code however I did not use code to disable the pin. It also states that the ALE is emitted at a constant rate of 1/6th the oscillator frequency.

What I want to do is identify if the microcontroller itself is garbage (by testing pins) before even trying to program it. The one I'm using is AT89C51-24PC.

I tried the reset to see if my code will execute with the micro on a breadboard to no avail. In the tests I tried an 8Mhz crystal with each leg grounded through 10pF caps without success. I then replaced that arrangement with just a 32Khz crystal and I still get the same result.

Now I tried hooking ALE to ground through an LED+ 1K resistor in series and the LED stays off. If I hooked ALE to VCC through LED + 1K resistor, the LED stays on.

Because I havent explicitly told the micro to disable ALE, I would expect the LED to blink at a high-speed but it is not.

In all tests, the reset pin is grounded through a 10K resistor.

Is my test of ALE sufficient enough or do I need to do something else hardware wise to check if the chip is internally damaged? (and no I'm not going to hook the pins to a high voltage source)

**UPDATE**

I fixed my programmer code so that the correct signals are sent to the chip yet I still have no luck.

My code is this:

```
mov R6,#0h
mov R7,#0h
l3:
l2:
l:
djnz R7,l
djnz R6,l2
dec P1
ljmp l3
END
```

When I tested the LED on the ALE pin now with 8Mhz crystal rammed into the breadboard with 10pF caps, the light seems to be running normally, however the output to P1 stays all logic high when it should be decrementing from 255 to 0 over and over again. when I connected the Led+Resistor from +ve to random pins (one at a time), I noticed PSEN made the led not light right after the reset was issued  but then I waited in hopes that it would come on because if the chip was literally never programmed, then FFh or 00h would be stored on the chip which from one source represents "Mov R7,A" and "nop" respectively. Neither instruction causes a loop so I figured if that's the case then when the chip wants the 4097th or later byte, wouldn't PSEN change state? (aka light up in my case)?

Now I feel I need to waste a circuit board just to test a chip, but are there other options here?

**update 2**

I don't get it. Now on the breadboard I decided to add a SIP resistor pack (so that all P0 pins are individually connected to VCC through 4.7K resistors), and when I connected the PSEN to VCC through the LED and 1K resistor, the LED was off at first then after a few seconds, it endlessly was blinking. I guess this tells me my program never entered the chip in the first place. I'm starting to think the EPROM in my chip is broken before I ever received it. I'm going to try other 8051 chips and see what happens.

Comment: Have you tried reading your code from the chip, assuming your chip shipped with 5V programming enabled? If you can read back your code, the chip is probably not broken.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Getting bad parts out of the box should not be a common thing.

Comment: One sixth of 32kHz is still _way_ too fast to see. It would just appear dimmer than normal.  Do you have an o-scope to look at it?

Comment: "If I hooked ALE to VCC through LED + 1K resistor, the LED stays on." - what is the voltage on ALE when you do this? Where did the chip come from?

Comment: I ordered the chip from futurlec.com and a dim light is better than a full-on light because it suggests that the clock is running fast. What I'm trying to solve is I want to see if the chip accepts any code and can function. I think my chip is faulty.

Comment: also, the voltage is a constant 4.94V from the ALE pin when I replaced the led+resistor with the voltmeter leads. I also run the whole circuit under a 5VDC adapter. I also measured the voltage with the LED +resistor in place by connecting the meter pins to the ALE pin and ground and the reading was roughly 2.5 volts but I think that's because of the LED.

Comment: Mike read this.... specifically what the RST pin needs and the AE pin. ALso your xtal caps are too small. 30pf is nominal. http://what-when-how.com/8051-microcontroller/pin-description-of-the-8051/

Comment: nano farads? well some documentation says 33pF but I'm curious as to why mine are small when I used different crystal speeds. I think the higher the crystal speed, the lower the cap? or am I thinking wrong?

Comment: My bad mistyped.. 33pF. I recall these beasts were fidgety In this dept though.. Breadboard capacitance can mess them up. We switched to oscilators because we never trusted the xtal to start 100% of the time under production conditions.

Comment: But RST needs to be held high for a few cycles to get it going, and EA must be connected to one rail or the other.

Comment: I have EA always connected to VCC in my tests (for internal addressing) and the reset pin is connected to ground through 10K and a 100uF capacitor from it to VCC. I know 100uF is ridiculous and it should be more like 2uF but I'm testing things. sometimes I short out the cap to issue a reset but even then I wait at least one second to see if anything happens in my favor and nothing does with the exception of the chip not blowing up (unless it was blown up before it arrived)

Comment: Do you have a scope? I'd bet the crystal just isn't starting. BTW they were always very sturdy beasts. I worked with them for 6 years, never blew one up yet. Other stuff ya...but those just kept on ticking.

Comment: no I don't have a scope, but I was doing another experiment on a breadboard, some timer using cmos 4060 chip and crystal with some resistors and capacitors and it was running but that was an 8 Mhz crystal. This circuit is similar: http://www.hackersbench.com/Projects/1Hz/

Comment: I don't recall what happens when you plug in a non-programmed chip mind you....

Comment: "I guess this tells me my program never entered the chip in the first place." - you should already know this because it would have failed to verify. "the LED was off at first then after a few seconds, it endlessly was **blinking**." - does that mean your program was running?

Comment: What I will try to do is spend more time programming each byte something like 10+ms per transistion just to see if the chip can work at all or if the internal eeprom no longer works for me.